# change words of beforeunload (leave this page and stay on this page) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

that alerts before leaving page like:

[image: alert to confirm before leaving page]

How can I change the the words "**Leave this page**" and "**Stay on this page**"?

Comment: Might find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Comment: It is browser dependent. Over the years it got so abused many browsers will only display defaults regardless of what you return as string